# Bulk selecting of checkboxes per table using javascript & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, bulk

I'm trying to make a bulk action function.

What I want:
- Bulk selection in multiple tables, but one `<form>`
- At every table one select box to select all items inside that table

Example of my code

```
<form method="post">
   <table class="list1">
     <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td class="bulkCheckbox nummer">
            <input type="checkbox" 
            name="checkProducts" onclick="checkAll('list1, this')" />
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <input class="bulkCheckbox" type="checkbox" 
           name="bulkCheckProduct[]" value="2810" />
         </td>
         <td>
           <input class="bulkCheckbox" type="checkbox" 
           name="bulkCheckProduct[]" value="2811" />
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>

   <table class="list2">
     <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td class="bulkCheckbox nummer">
            <input type="checkbox" 
            name="checkProducts" onclick="checkAll('list2, this')" />
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <input class="bulkCheckbox" type="checkbox" 
           name="bulkCheckProduct[]" value="2812" />
         </td>
         <td>
           <input class="bulkCheckbox" type="checkbox" 
           name="bulkCheckProduct[]" value="2813" />
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</form> 



<script>
function checkAll(table, bx) {

    var checkname = document.table.getElementsByClassName("bulkCheckbox");

    for (i = checkname.length; i--; ) {
        checkname[i].checked = bx.checked;
    }
}
</script>
```

Now I got the php part worked, so when I select multiple select boxes, the $_POST returns my values.
Also the Javascript part worked for me, so select all checkboxes per table.
But Javascript and PHP together won't work for me..

How can I fix this to let the JS and PHP work together?
I've tried multiple scripts but none of them worked for me.

The error I get from JS:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByName' of undefined
```

What I try, nothing works..

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```js
 
function checkAll(table, bx) {

    var checkname = document.getElementsByClassName("bulkCheckbox");

    for (i = checkname.length; i--; ) {
  console.log(checkname[i]);
  console.log(bx);
        checkname[i].checked = bx.checked;
    }
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
   <table class="list1">
     <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td class="bulkCheckbox nummer">
            <input type="checkbox" 
            name="checkProducts" onclick="checkAll('list1', this)" />
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <input class="bulkCheckbox" type="checkbox" 
           name="bulkCheckProduct[]" value="2810" />
         </td>
         <td>
           <input class="bulkCheckbox" type="checkbox" 
           name="bulkCheckProduct[]" value="2811" />
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>

   <table class="list2">
     <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td class="bulkCheckbox nummer">
            <input type="checkbox" 
            name="checkProducts" onclick="checkAll('list2', this)" />
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <input class="bulkCheckbox" type="checkbox" 
           name="bulkCheckProduct[]" value="2812" />
         </td>
         <td>
           <input class="bulkCheckbox" type="checkbox" 
           name="bulkCheckProduct[]" value="2813" />
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</form>
```

'this' the parameter you are passing in checkAll() is passed as a string.

Comment: thanks for your reply, this worked for me, but one thing. Now it checks all of the checkboxes, because of the variable `table` is not used anymore. This variable is to separate the tables from each other. But I can't get it work to use this variable in combi with the `getElementsByClassname`